# How to call a wxFrame from a different file in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to call a wxFrame from a different file so I don't have a bunch of code in one single file. I want to have the settings window be in a separate file so the code is easier to read for me. This is the code I tried to get to work but nothing showed up:

```
def test():
    import wx
    class oranges(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self,parent,id):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, 'TEST',size=(500,500))
            self.frame=wx.Panel(self)


    if __name__ =='__main__':
        app = wx.App(False)
        window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
        window.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

I want to be able to just import the file and call the function test() and the window will pop up. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the above is in file `orange.py`. Delete or dedent the if part. As it is written now, it will do nothing.

Create a second file `main.py`. You can copy over the if part from the other file to start the `wx.App`.

Then you have to import the frame and create an instance.

In file orange.py:

```
import wx
class oranges(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, 'TEST',size=(500,500))
        self.frame=wx.Panel(self)
```

In file main.py:

```
import wx
from orange import oranges

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    window = oranges(parent=None,id=-1)
    window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```